# c# find keywords in a string and remove it

Tags: c#, string

I have got a list with keywords. And I coded a method that if a string contains keyword from list, the method must remove keyword from string. Here is the method:

```
private string RemoveFromList(string sentence)
{
    var lists = new List<string>{ "ask-", "que-", "(app)", "(exe)", "(foo)" };
    var control = lists.Any(sentence.Contains);
    string result;
    if (control)
    {
        var index = sentence.IndexOf(lists.FirstOrDefault(sentence.Contains) 
                 ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), StringComparison.Ordinal);
        result = index != -1 ? sentence.Remove(index) : sentence;
    }
    else
        result = sentence;
    return result;
}

var str = "ask- This is a sentence.";
Message.Box(RemoveFromList(str));
// It does not give to me: This is a sentence.
```

This method does not work properly. It does not remove the keyword from the string.

Comment: What doesn't work properly?

Comment: Have you run your code in the debugger?  Where is it not working correctly?

Comment: i suggest you use a regex replace.

Comment: @Isitar I'm not exactly sure that regex is all that necessary nor ideal for what they're asking.

Comment: You could just do `sentence.Replace("ask-","").Replace("que-","")....Trim()` if it's a short, static list.

Comment: @Dortimer alternativly you could chain multipple Replace statements

Comment: In your code, how did you expect `Remove(index)` to know how many characters to remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `string.Replace` is the simplest approach:

```
foreach (var word in lists)
{
   sentence = sentence.Replace(word,"").Trim();
}
```

Although that will find the word in the middle of the string too. If you wanted to remove it only at the start you could use `IndexOf` check it's 0 and then take the string starting from `word.Length` using `Substring`.  Or use `StartsWith`:

```
foreach (var word in lists)
{
   if (sentence.StartsWith(word))
   {
       sentence = sentence.Substring(word.Length).Trim();
     // break; // if only one
   }
}
```

Comment: This returns `ask- This is a sentence.`

Comment: @HabipOğuz It doesn't. Check your code, did you return `sentence` after the replacement?  If I do `string s = "ask- this is a test"; s = s.Replace("ask-",""); Console.WriteLine(s);` it returns `" this is a test"`.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was solved when I use `string.Trim()`, Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options for you.

1. First of all the Remove usage is incorrect. You just want to remove the keyword. If u pass 1 argument to remove it will remove from that index till end. Pass the length of keyword as second arg to Remove.

   s.Remove(index, len);
2. If string contains it than replace the occurrence of keyword with empty string

   s.Replace("keyword", "");

Answer (score 0):

Another option is you could create an extension since you already know what items to remove.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static string RemoveFromList(this string sentence)
{
    new List<string>{ "ask-", 
                     "que-", 
                     "(app)", 
                     "(exe)", 
                     "(foo)" }.ForEach(name => 
                                       {
                                           sentence = Regex.Replace(sentence.Replace(name, string.Empty), " {2,}", " ");
                                       });          
    return sentence;
}
```

**Useage**

```
 var str = "ask- This is (app) a que- sentence.".RemoveFromList();
```

**Note**

I used `Regex.Replace` as it's possible you may have some blank spaces floating around after you remove the bad string/s, this helps ensure that doesn't happen.